# xdg-open from .desktop file (in script)

Tags: shell-script, .desktop, xdg-open, xdg

I am trying to get a shell script to launch a browser. When run standalone, this script successfully opens a browser with

```
xdg-open http://localhost:8080
```

However, I am trying to make it convenient newbie-friendly, so I've created a .desktop file which launches this script (linuxStart.sh)

Here's the .desktop file

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Start Application
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=./linuxStart.sh
Categories=Application;
```

So far so good. But when run this way, it seems xdg-open does not run, and the browser does not open. The command is ignored inside the script. What gives?

I have tried inserting

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
```

on top of the .desktop file with no effect

Here is linuxStart.sh (proof of concept)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

#Other commands (runs fine)
#...

#Does not run from the .desktop file
xdg-open http://localhost:8080
```

Thanks

OS: MX Linux 19.04

DE: Xfce

Comment: Likely impossible to answer without knowing how you are "running" the .desktop file and, maybe, what the content of `linuxStart.sh` is, but your issue is most likely related to `Exec=./linuxStart.sh`: the Desktop Entry Specification [states](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) that the `Exec` key must be either a full path or a name, which is in turn searched for in your `PATH`. Does the directory that contains `linuxStart.sh` appear in your `PATH`?

Comment: Thanks. No, it's not in my path. The idea is to make a portable app for linux (for [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki)). Since it should be run from Dropbox, USB, etc. (and be user-friendly) I cannot use the full path. The command however executes fine, it simply ignores the xdg-open command. I'll post the linuxStart.sh as well.

Comment: Thank you for you edit. I wouldn't know how it's supposed to work on MX Linux/Xfce but, on Arch Linux + KDE, `Exec=./foo` only works if `foo` can be found through a `PATH` search. So (based on the aforementioned Desktop Entry Specification) I'm reasonably sure `Exec=./foo` isn't portable. (How should the program interpreting the .desktop file guess the actual path `.` is meant to refer to? Note that .desktop files are also used by menus and launchers, which generally won't have an intuitive concept of "current working directory").

Comment: That said, trying to be more helpful with the issue you describe: how are you detecting that `xdg-open http://localhost:8080` is not executed, while others command are? Are you watching the script running in a terminal emulator? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I got it working!! I simply removed `Terminal=true`. It seemed to launch a separate X terminal and mess things up. I did not see any error messages. Can you reproduce on Arch? Thank you!

Comment: Yep. What you are seeing is (likely) that `xdg-open` returns immediately, the script ends and the pseudo-terminal the script was connected to is destroyed, causing the browser started by `xdg-open` to terminate. As you found out, `Terminal=false` prevents this (because no terminal emulator is launched and no pseudo-terminal is created). Alternatively, you should be able to stick to `Terminal=true` and use `nohup xdg-open http://localhost:8080`. I'm not completely sure though, that's why I'm not posting a proper answer.

Comment: @fra-san I did test and it never seems to work with `Terminal=true`, even with `nohup`, no sure what's the cause.

Comment: I've tested on Nautilus and unfortunately it doesn't launch on double-click...  Unfortunately it seems like I need to compromise for usability. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

By removing `Terminal=true` the file now seems to run. The user does need to set all files executable for this to work (which is ok I guess). It open with double click in Thunar.

```bsh
#Works fine
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Start Application
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=./linuxStart.sh
Categories=Application;
```

It seemed to be launching another X terminal which was causing problems.